# How to set the color of a single word without changing the color of all the text?

Tags: c++, windows, colors

I would like to know how to change the color of text. I know how to do something like:

system("color 0a")

Which would change the color of all displayed characters to a light green. However, is it possible to write a sentence in C++ that outputs as:

Hello world, I am user3554369!

Where all of the text is white *except* "username3554369," which would be green?

It does not have to be cross-platform. Assume all users will be running Windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check the second answer here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/5830/ .

It uses the [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Windows API function, which seems to be a much better idea than using `system()`.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure how to do that. Could you (or someone else) show me an example?

Comment: The first link in my answer has an example.